# How to validate a complex schema using meta-schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to validate some schemas that I already have against to a meta-schema using the Ajv lib. I'm getting the result that the schemas are valid even when if I change it to an invalid definition.

**This is one schema:**

```js
{
  "id": "TEST_SCHEMA",
  "name": "TEST_SCHEMA",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "isEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "name": "isEnabled",
      "default": false
    },
    "options": {
      "type": "array",
      "name": "options",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "content": {
            "type": "string",
            "name": "content",
            "default": ""
          },
          "isChecked": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "name": "isChecked",
            "default": true
          },
          "entities": {
            "type": "array",
            "name": "entities",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "club",
                    "businessPartners"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "channels": {
            "type": "array",
            "name": "channels",
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": [
                    "email",
                    "phone",
                    "sms",
                    "post"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**This is my meta-schema:**

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://www.example.com/meta-schema.json#",
  "title": "Core schema meta-schema",
  "definitions": {
    "schemaArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": { "$ref": "#" }
    },
    "schemaObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1,
      "patternProperties": {
        "^([A-Za-z0-9_$]){2,}$": {"$ref": "#"}
      },
      "additionalProperties": fanlse
    },
    "simpleTypes": {
      "enum": [
        "array",
        "boolean",
        "integer",
        "null",
        "number",
        "object",
        "string",
        "function"
      ]
    },
    "stringArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" },
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "default": []
    }
  },
  "type": ["object", "boolean"],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri-reference"
    },
    "$ref": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uri-reference"
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "default": true,
    "readOnly": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "pattern": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "regex"
    },
    "items": {
      "$ref": "#",
      "default": true
    },
    "uniqueItems": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "required": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" },
    "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
    "definitions": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": { "$ref": "#" },
      "default": {}
    },
    "properties": {
      "$ref": "#",
      "default": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "$ref": "#" },
          { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringArray" }
        ]
      }
    },
    "propertyNames": { "$ref": "#" },
    "enum": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": true,
      "minItems": 1,
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "type": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/simpleTypes" },
          "minItems": 1,
          "uniqueItems": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "default": true
}
```

**How I'm using Ajv:**

```js
  const ajv = new Ajv({
    allErrors: true,
    schemaId: `auto`,
    extendRefs: `fail`,
    schemas: refs,
    meta: META_SCHEMA
  })

  try {
    ajv.validateSchema(schema)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Schema Validation Error:`, file, error)
    console.table(ajv.errors, [`keyword`,`params`,`message`])
  }
```

I expect the schemas to fail when they have an invalid definition.

**My meta-schema is wrong or am I using Ajv in wrong way?**

Comment: What do you mean by “invalid definitions”? What do you think is wrong with your Schema that you expect to be picked up?

Comment: The meta Schema is standard by the way

Comment: "Invalid definition" I mean is when I have some definitions of the meta-schema violated, like define a type as "list". @Relequestual

Comment: Ok. You need to provide a specific example so others can reproduce the issue if you expect help here. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example